# Substituting values in SymPy summation

Tags: python, sympy

When substituting values into a SymPy sum, it doesn't seem to recognise that the variables are indexed, and simply factors out all the indexed variables, like so:

```py
# Define variables.
z_tilde_i = sympy.IndexedBase('\\tilde{z}')
rho_i = sympy.IndexedBase('\\rho')
M = sympy.symbols('M')
n = sympy.symbols('n', integer = True)
i = sympy.Idx('i', n)

# Define equation M = sum(rho * deltaZ).
eq_total_mass = sympy.Eq(M, sympy.Sum(rho_i[i] * (z_tilde_i[i + 1] - z_tilde_i[i]), (i, 0, n - 1)))

# Try to substitute values.
print(eq_total_mass.rhs.subs(n, 3).doit())
>>> 3*(\tilde{z}[i + 1] - \tilde{z}[i])*\rho[i]
```

How to make the SymPy sum recognise the indexed variables?

Comment: This is a bug. If you change `i` to be an ordinary symbol then it works. This should be reported to GitHub: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `i` as ordinary symbol and it worked. I will report on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround:

There is no need to define i as Idx:

```
>>> i = var('i')
>>> Sum(rho_i[i] * (z_tilde_i[i + 1] - z_tilde_i[i]), (i, 0, 1)).doit()
(-\tilde{z}[0] + \tilde{z}[1])*\rho[0] + (-\tilde{z}[1] + \tilde{z}[2])*\rho[1]
```

Or if you do, don't use the `integer=True` when defining `n`:

```
>>> n = var('n')
>>> i = sympy.Idx('i', n)
>>> Sum(rho_i[i] * (z_tilde_i[i + 1] - z_tilde_i[i]), (i, 0, 1)).doit()
(-\tilde{z}[0] + \tilde{z}[1])*\rho[0] + (-\tilde{z}[1] + \tilde{z}[2])*\rho[1]
```